# Correct Regex in SFTP bash script

Tags: bash, shell, sftp, glob, heredoc

I want to automate a SFTP process to transfer the last file created in local server and send it to remote server.

In local server I have "/Source/Path/" I have files named like below:

```
Logfile_2019-04-24
Logfile_2019-04-24_old.txt
```

This is my current script:

```
dyear=`date +'%Y' -d "1 day ago"`
dmonth=`date +'%b' -d "1 day ago"`
ddate=`date +%Y-%m-%d -d "1 day ago"`


HOST='192.168.X.X'
USER='user'
PASSWD='password'
localpath='/Source/Path/'$dyear'/'$dmonth'/'*$ddate*'.txt'
remotepath='/Destination/Path/'$dyear'/'$dmonth'/'

echo $localpath
echo $remotepath

export SSHPASS=$PASSWD
sshpass -e sftp $USER@$HOST << EOF
put '$localpath' '$remotepath'
EOF
```

When I do `echo $localpath` it prints the correct file but in the script I get this error:

```
Connecting to 192.168.X.X...
sftp> put '/Source/Path/2019/Apr/*2019-04-24*' '/Destination/Path/2019/Apr/'
stat /Source/Path/2019/Apr/*2019-04-24*: No such file or directory
```

How would be the correct regex in this pasrt `*$ddate*'.txt' in following`line:

```
    localpath='/Source/Path/'$dyear'/'$dmonth'/'*$ddate*'.txt'
```

in order to transfer the file "Logfile_2019-04-24_old.txt"?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using globs to match multiple files, or trying to grab one specific one?
https://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob

Comment: @vintnes I'm tryng to match a single file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
put '$localpath' '$remotepath'
```

with

```
put "$(echo $localpath)" '$remotepath'
```

to force wildcard (`*`) replacement in your here-doc.

This does not work if your wildcard is replaced by multiple files.

Comment: Excellent Cyrus. It works perfectly. Thanks so much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need a regex for this problem. You can get the latest file created in the directory by the following shell command and assign it to your localpath variable.

```
ls -t directoryPath | head -n1

latestfile=`ls -t /Source/Path/$dyear/$dmonth | head -n1`
localpath='/Source/Path/'$dyear'/'$dmonth'/'$latestfile''
remotepath='/Destination/Path/'$dyear'/'$dmonth'/'
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. The thing is if the last file is named like `Logfile_2019-04-24` I'd transfer the incorrect file. Because of that I add the regex  `*$ddate*.txt` trying to match a file named like `Logfile_2019-04-24_old.txt` in case that file be of the same date but not the last created.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to get the filename, source and destination directories properly, you can directly use `scp` to copy the file to remote server:

```
sshpass -p $PASSWD scp $localpath $USER@$HOST:$remotepath
```

Comment: Thanks for answer Lohit. The issue is the remote server only accepts SFTP.

Comment: Also instead of using multiple single quotes, while defining the path variables, you can directly use a Double quote, it will substitute the values automatically.

Comment: The issue here is that put command does not support meta characters. Also it takes a single argument. You will have to rewrite the code to fetch the exact filename and then use put statement. Ref. [this link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26502_01/html/E29001/remotehowtoaccess-14.html)